# Git revert cherry pick on pull request branch without reverting on master

Tags: git, github, merge, git-revert, git-cherry-pick

I read that I can use git revert to undo a cherry-pick. I tried to cherry-pick a commit from the master branch on a project, but not I realize I don't want to do it. Unfortunately for me, I've already pushed.

What I'm afraid of is if I use git revert, I don't know if it will revert the commit on master too when the PR is merged.

How can I undo the cherry-pick without messing up the master branch after a merge?

This is not intended to be a duplicate, I just want to undo it on the pull request branch and don't want to undo it on master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it.  Git is a distributed SCM—you can merge the feature branch into `master` on your local repository and see what happens without anybody else noticing.  (Don't forget to revert your experiments afterwards.)  If you want to be extra secure, copy your repository first and try it in the copy.

That said, you are safe.  The commit won't be reverted in `master`.

Comment: I guess I was only looking at GitHub's docs. I've got to remember how important this is to keep in mind, it worked. Master was kept safe and using `git fetch --all` and then `git reset --hard origin/master` I was able to undo my experiment in master and just pushed the PR branch.